# Can I disable the mouse for LightDM?

Tags: drivers, graphics, lightdm

LightDM is having major problems with the xserver and generic graphics driver on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for me, and I really don't like the look and feel of GDM or LXDM, so I just want to disable the mouse on the LightDM login screen instead, to fix the jittery mouse problem and force guests to learn the arrow key method instead.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean the unity-greeter?  lightdm is the backend service.  You could try an alternative greeter like the gtk one.

Answer (score 0):

First use the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to find out your mouse id:

```
xinput list
```

Once you find it, run the following commands for editing `lightdm.conf` file with root privileges:

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following two lines at the end of `lightdm.conf` file:

```bsh
greeter-setup-script=xinput --disable <mouse_id>
session-setup-script=xinput --enable <mouse_id>
#replace <mouse_id> with the id of the mouse that you found it with `xinput list` command
```

Save the file and close it and don't forget to close that root shell.

Now, reboot your system and use only the keyboard at the login screen.